# Google App Engine - PM2 - Start program failed: failed to detect app after start: ForAppStart():

Tags: google-app-engine, pm2, app-engine-flexible

Im running an app on Google App Engine, its a simple node js application, the start command i run it with is `pm2 start build/index.js` but i keep getting this error `Start program failed: failed to detect app after start: ForAppStart():`

Comment: Hi @Kravitz could you please provide more details regarding your case? Are you trying to start your application or deploy it on App Engine? If you could provide more details on if the issue is after a successful deploy to GAE or if it's before, it would help for a better understanding of your case.

Comment: Its literally after deploying a new instance up, I see that the nginx proxy starts and then as node tried to run `npm run start` I see pm2 trying to start then this error

Comment: Hi @Kravitz thanks for the confirmation! It seems that it's related to how you're starting your application. This message is related to the fact that your application not recognizing the startup. For this reason, I would recommend you to check out this documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#application_startup) and give it a try the steps and details on how to initiate your Node.js application. Could you please give it a try?